# Elantech Multi-touch not working

Tags: touchpad

I'm running 16.04LTS with the 4.13.0-36-generic kernel with the X11 desktop on my samsung np780z5e. The touchpad shows up as ETPS/2 Elantech touchpad. My right click, left click, scroll, and basic movements work, but the three finger and four finger gestures don't work. I've seen this thread from a few years ago: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442

where the author of comment 77 came up with a patch that applies to the 3.8 kernel. Would it be a bad idea to downgrade to using that kernel and fix? Thank you.